# Array data not showing

Tags: arrays, reactjs, local-storage

In a react component I am storing data in the localStorage using a network call in this way:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getCategoryList().then((category) => {
      setCategories(category.data.data.map((result: any) => ({ ...result })));
      localStorage.setItem("categories", JSON.stringify(category));
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  console.log({ categories });
```

I am retrieving this data from localStorage in another component in this way:

```
const categories = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("categories") || "{}");
console.log(categories);
```

From the localStorage the data structure is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "fetched categories successfully",
        "success": true,
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "diagnostic",
                "slug": "hospital",
                "description": "diagnostic center",
                "status": "active",
                "created_by": "tripping_card",
                "updated_by": "nabila",
                "created_at": "2021-04-06T12:07:18.195Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-15T10:47:01.04Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Private Chamber",
                "slug": "private-chamber",
                "description": "Private Chamber as care provider",
                "status": "active",
                "created_by": "tripping_card",
                "updated_by": "tripping_card",
                "created_at": "2021-04-06T16:46:27.313Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-06T16:46:27.313Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Diagnostic Center",
                "slug": "diagnostic-center",
                "description": "Diagnostic Center as care provider",
                "status": "active",
                "created_by": "01400000000",
                "updated_by": "01400000000",
                "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:46:39.684Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:46:39.684Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Blood Bank",
                "slug": "fgf",
                "description": "Shondhani Blood Bank service provider",
                "status": "active",
                "created_by": "ishak",
                "updated_by": "ishak",
                "created_at": "2021-04-12T11:31:56.525Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-13T09:06:38.508Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Organ Center",
                "slug": "center",
                "description": "Center for Organ donation",
                "status": "inactive",
                "created_by": "ishak",
                "updated_by": "ishak",
                "created_at": "2021-04-12T11:33:57.136Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-13T11:35:04.468Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Health Card",
                "slug": "provide",
                "description": "Center to Provide health card",
                "status": "active",
                "created_by": "ishak",
                "updated_by": "ishak",
                "created_at": "2021-04-12T11:50:49.064Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-13T09:08:10.101Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Patient Sample Collection",
                "slug": "sample",
                "description": "Collect Blood and other samples",
                "status": "inactive",
                "created_by": "ishak",
                "updated_by": "ishak",
                "created_at": "2021-04-12T11:51:47.529Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-13T11:37:28.52Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Clinic",
                "slug": "clinic",
                "description": "Green Delta Clinic",
                "status": "active",
                "created_by": "ishak",
                "updated_by": "ishak",
                "created_at": "2021-04-12T12:01:22.077Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-18T05:39:19.967Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "DGHS",
                "slug": "dghs",
                "description": "Govt Hospital",
                "status": "inactive",
                "created_by": "ishak",
                "updated_by": "ishak",
                "created_at": "2021-04-14T06:23:14.172Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-14T06:41:01.175Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Hospital",
                "slug": "hospital",
                "description": "Hospital as primary provider",
                "status": "active",
                "created_by": "nabila",
                "updated_by": "nabila",
                "created_at": "2021-04-15T17:31:21.105Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-15T17:31:21.105Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "content-length": "676",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "config": {
        "url": "https://api-dev.evaly.com.bd/ehealth-provider/api/v1/admin/category",
        "method": "get",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImlzaGFrIiwiZ3JvdXBzIjpbIlZvdWNoZXJWaWV3ZXIiLCJOb3RlRW50cnkiLCJDaGF0TWFuYWdlciIsIk5vdGVNYW5hZ2VyIiwiZWJhemFyTWFuYWdlciIsIkJ1bGtBZG1pbiIsIk9yZGVyTWFuYWdlciIsIkNhbXBhaWduTWFuYWdlciIsIkNhbXBhaWduQWRtaW4iLCJCcmFuZE1hbmFnZXIiLCJQcm9kdWN0TWFuYWdlciIsIkNoYXRBZG1pbiIsIkVmb29kTWFuYWdlciIsIkFjY291bnRzQWRtaW4iLCJTaG9wT3duZXIiLCJCYWxhbmNlTWFuYWdlciIsIkVmb29kQ3VzdG9tZXJTZXJ2aWNlIiwiRWZvb2RBZG1pbiIsIkRhdGFFeHBvcnRlciIsIkFwcG9pbnRtZW50QWRtaW4iLCJDYXRlZ29yeU1hbmFnZXIiLCJFa2hhdGFBZG1pbiIsIkVmb29kQ29udGVudE1hbmFnZXIiLCJFdmFseUVtcGxveWVlIiwiVGVjaFN1cHBvcnQiLCJTaG9wTWFuYWdlciIsIkNhc2hiYWNrQWRtaW4iLCJlYmF6YXJBZG1pbiIsIklzc3VlUmVzb2x1dGlvbk1hbmFnZXIiLCJPcmRlclN0YXR1c1VwZGF0ZSIsIlByb2R1Y3RBZG1pbiIsIkhlcm9NYW5hZ2VyIiwiVm91Y2hlckFkbWluIiwiRWZvb2RDb250ZW50QWRtaW4iLCJJc3N1ZVJlc29sdXRpb25BZG1pbiIsIlZvdWNoZXJNYW5hZ2VyIiwiTm90aWZpY2F0aW9uTWFuYWdlciIsIk9yZGVyQ2FuY2VsIiwiQ29tcGFueUFkbWluIiwiRWpvYnNFdmFseUFkbWluIiwiQnVsa1Blcm1pc3Npb24iLCJTaG9wQWRtaW4iLCJPcmRlckFkbWluIiwiVGVjaEFkbWluIiwiQ29tcGFueU1hbmFnZXIiLCJBY2NvdW50c01hbmFnZXIiLCJSZWZ1bmRNYW5hZ2VyIiwiSFJNYW5hZ2VyIiwiRW1wbG95ZWVNYW5hZ2VyIiwiQXNzZXRNYW5hZ2VyIiwiSFJBZG1pbiIsIkhlcm9BZG1pbiJdLCJmaXJzdF9uYW1lIjoiSXNoYWsiLCJsYXN0X25hbWUiOiJBaGFtbWVkIiwiaXNfc3RhZmYiOnRydWUsImlzX2FjdGl2ZSI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNfc3VwZXJ1c2VyIjp0cnVlLCJ2ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwidXNlcl90eXBlIjoiZW1wbG95ZWUiLCJ1c2VyX3N0YXR1cyI6ImFjdGl2ZSIsImVtYWlsIjoic29tZUBlbWFpbC5uZXQiLCJjb250YWN0IjoiMDEzMjQ4MjM0Li4iLCJkYXRlX2pvaW5lZCI6IjIwMTktMDgtMjlUMTI6MTA6MzhaIiwidG9rZW5fdHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsImlzX2VhdXRoIjp0cnVlLCJleHAiOjE2MTg3ODU1NzV9.PhRCPslJyjYj7PqKVgKzfEFi8gE6mnmsO1alcCj791Y"
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

Now I am mapping this data like this:

```
{categories &&
            categories.data.data.map(
              ({ category }: { category: any }, { index }: { index: any }) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  {category && category.length > 0
                    ? category.slug
                    : "No data"}
                </div>
              )
            )}
```

But its not printing the slugs rather its printing `No Data` 10 times. I am not sure whats wrong with the code block.

Comment: Where is `length` property in your shared **data-structure** ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur here I am checking the length of the category array using `category.length > 0`

Comment: If `category` was an array, how could it be having `category.slug` as a property ?. `category` seems to be an object.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I would like to map on this array

`"data": [
            {
                "name": "diagnostic",
                "slug": "hospital",
                "description": "diagnostic center",
                "status": "active",
                "created_by": "tripping_card",
                "updated_by": "nabila",
                "created_at": "2021-04-06T12:07:18.195Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-15T10:47:01.04Z"
            },
        ]`

Comment: Also you seem to be destructuring `category` (when using `{category}`) but I think the array item itself is `category` object. Kindly check on that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below if `categories` is a state (This is because you seem to have remapped from that data-structure to just having `categories` array as your state inside the `useEffect`) :-

```
{categories.map(
              (category:any, index:any ) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    {category.slug}
                </div>
              )
            )}
```

**Note :-** Here I have assumed that `categories` state default value is `[]` i.e. an empty array.

Also in case you're directly picking stuff from `localStorage` and then trying to render it, the **mapping** should be like so :-

```
{categories &&
            categories.data.data.map(
              (category:any, index : any) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  {category.slug}
                </div>
              )
            )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.length` on the `category` object. try this:

```
{category ? category.slug : "No data"}
```

Comment: its printing `No Data` 10 times